# Git bash with Chinese?

Tags: git, chinese, git-bash

I have a few folders with Chinese characters in them. I simply want to cd into them in Git bash, but this is impossible since I can't type Chinese in its terminal. Is there a plug-in of some sort that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

A general approach to be able to operate on any directory (or file) is to use its inode number.

First, use ls to get the inode of the folder in question:

```
ls -lia
```

- `-l` for long listing (optional)
- `-i` to get inode values
- `-a` to view all files, even hidden files (optional)

In the listing you'll see a long number in the first column, something like this:

```
2104697 drwx------ 2 user group 4096 date time WEIRD_DIRNAME
```

Now you can change to that directory using:

```
cd "$(find -inum ######)"
```

...but substituting ###### with the long number that you got in the directory listing.

Of course the command doesn't have to be `cd`.  It could be `rm`, `cp`, `mv`, *etc*...

[Source](https://superuser.com/posts/537883/edit)